# Error: unknown command "kubernetes" for "doctl"

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

When I run the following command to save cluster context from digitalocean:

```
doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save api-cluster
```

I get following error:

[Screenshot of the Error after the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es1NZ.png)

Comment: Have you checked the version of `doctl` you're using? (It looks like the kubernetes command came out of beta in 1.18.0)

Answer (score 1):

update `doctl` latest version from https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases

Comment: I had installed the doctl a few days ago.

Comment: what is your doctl version? can you check?

Comment: same issues, version 1.73.0-windows